# Exterior Home security/Lighting compatibility

Tags: alarm

Are there any exteriour security lighting systems via sensor or light you can connect to your exterior home lights for security..

For example if there are sensors I could buy and put around my big yard and if these sensors were to be set off by an intruder is it possible to somehow have all the exterior lights on my house by this sensor or have it wired to do so.

Is there a product like this on the market?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement.  Unfortunately shopping assistance / product recommendation questions are off topic.

Comment: In my last home I had a long circle driveway I used 3 motion detectors 1 at each end of the driveway and 1 looking at the front entry. I ran the power for all 3 using 12-3 with ground powering the sensors with the normal black white then tied the motion sensors output (normally red wire) to the extra conductor and this also connected to the black for each lamp. It worked great if any one entered the driveway all the lights turned on or if coming out the front door there was light to see. I did end up adding an over ride switch so I could keep the lights on longer than the timers.

Comment: Yes, you can buy motion sensors and lights separately.

Answer (score 1):

Several companies make separate Passive Infrared (PIR) detectors that could be used for your purpose. Or you could just mount motion detector lights in chosen locations or on the outside of the house. That is what most people opt for. Tying the whole thing together could be done but at an added cost that most people don't want to spend for what they get out of it.

Half of solving all design problems is getting familiar with the available products. This comes from experience and research. Spend some time browsing the net for motion detector type lights and sensors. You will find lots to choose from.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, and now there are a ton of 12V motion sensors designed to work with 12V LEDs.  Cost is much lower, but hard to wheel long distances.